# Understanding Vよりも前

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from a conversation between me and my language partner. This is her reply to a question I had about てform + おく:

「送っておきました」 と 「送りました」 の大きな違いは、行為の前後関係がはっきりしているかどうかです。
動詞のテ形 + おく の基本的な意味は、「後に起こることを予想して、前もって何かをする」 ということです。
（ to do something in advance for the future convenience.)

「送っておきました」 が意味するのは、「後でアンドレアスさんにメッセージを書くことを予想して、前もってスタンプを Skype の方に送った」 です。
「送りました」 の場合、過去形になっているので、メッセージを書くよりも前に送ったことになりますが、メッセージとの関係は示されていません。「送った」 という事実を言っているだけです。

the sentence in question:
「送りました」 の場合、過去形になっているので、メッセージを書くよりも前に送ったことになりますが、メッセージとの関係は示されていません。

My attempt at translation:
"In case of '送りました' , because it is past tense, even though it turns out that you have sent it from before writing the message, you have sent it, concerning the relation to the message, it isn't shown."

I'm not entirely sure wether I handled the phrase メッセージを書くよりも前に送った correctly. I think that メッセージを書くよりも前に refers to the writing of the message to which the meaning of て-form + おく points. 送った should refer to the Skype stickers she sent me before she wrote the message to which て-form + おく pointed, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to translate that literally because English does not respond well to subjectless verb constructions.

For

> 「送りました」 の場合、過去形になっているので、メッセージを書くよりも前に送ったことになりますが、メッセージとの関係は示されていません。

I would translate it as:

> In the case of 「送りました」, because this is in the past tense, it is clear that [they] were sent before typing the message, but it does not indicate any relation with the message.

I don't think "even though it turns out" is a good translation for ことになります
 here. One important thing to remember is that なる・なります sometimes functions as a copula verb in Japanese and doesn't always have the strong connotations of 成る / become.

In short, what she's trying to explain is that the 〜ておきました (～ておいた) form indicates that the action was undertaken as preparation for the other action. E.g., I shaved the morning because I wanted to look nice for my interview.

Conversely, the ～ました (〜た) past form merely indicates that one event occurred before another with no clear indication of whether the two events were related.

ておいた tells us did A and did A as preparation for B.
た tells us did A before B.